# Access Violation trying to read vector filled with objects

Tags: c++, vector, clone, copy-constructor

> edit: I made some changes and updated the code in this post based on
>   the comments of Kyle and Dieter, so I fixed my Clone()function and
>   added a assignment-operator to fulfil the rule of three. While this
>   fixes were for sure badly needed, the same error prevails. Maybe my
>   assignment operator is wrong?

I'm using the library jsonplus I found online for a bigger project.
I need to save objects of the Class CJsonArray in a vector.
CJsonArray comes with no Copy-Constructor but has a pointer attribute, so I tried to make one myself (first time I made a copy-constructor, I'm new to c++).

Here is the relevant part of CJsonArray:

cjsonarray.h

```
    class CJsonArray : public CJsonValue
    {
    private:
      std::vector <CJsonValue*> members;
    public:
        LIB_PRE CJsonArray();
        LIB_PRE CJsonArray(const CJsonArray * value);
        LIB_PRE CJsonArray(const CJsonArray &); //the added copy constructor
        LIB_PRE CJsonArray& operator=(const CJsonArray&);
        LIB_PRE ~CJsonArray();
```

cjsonarray.cpp

```
 CJsonArray::CJsonArray(const CJsonArray& ori) : members(ori.members.size()) {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < ori.members.size()-1; ++i)
            members[i] =ori.members[i]->Clone();
    }
CJsonArray& CJsonArray::operator=(const CJsonArray& ori){
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < ori.members.size() - 1; ++i){
        this->members[i] = ori.members[i]->Clone();
    }   
    return *this;
}
```

Aditionally I had to implement a clone() function in CJsonValue, which is an abstract class and the classes derived from it. Here are the relevant code snippets:

cjsonvalue.h

```
enum CJsonValueType
{
  JV_STRING,
  JV_NUMBER,
  JV_OBJECT,
  JV_ARRAY,
  JV_NULL,
  JV_BOOL
};

class CJsonValue
{
private:
  CJsonValueType type;
public:
  LIB_PRE CJsonValue();
  LIB_PRE virtual ~CJsonValue();
  LIB_PRE CJsonValue(CJsonValueType type);
  LIB_PRE virtual CJsonValue * Clone(); //the added Clone-Function
  LIB_PRE virtual jstring ToString() const = 0;
  LIB_PRE CJsonValueType GetType() const;
  LIB_PRE virtual void Clear(){};
};
```

cjsonvalue.cpp

```
    CJsonValue * CJsonValue::Clone(){
    return NULL;
}
```

example of derived class, cjsonvaluenumber.h

```
    class CJsonValueNumber : public CJsonValue
{
private:
  int value;
public:
  LIB_PRE CJsonValueNumber(int value);
  LIB_PRE CJsonValueNumber(const CJsonValueNumber * value);
  LIB_PRE CJsonValue * Clone();
  LIB_PRE jstring ToString() const;
  LIB_PRE void GetValue(int & number) const;
};
```

cjsonvaluenumber.cpp

```
CJsonValue * CJsonValueNumber::Clone(){
    return new CJsonValueNumber(*this);
}
```

main.cpp that produces the error:

```
 CJsonArray array1;
 CJsonArray array2;
 CJsonArray array3;
 CJsonArray array4;
 CJsonArray array5;

 array1.AddMember("test1");
 array2.AddMember("test1");
 array3.AddMember("test1");
 array4.AddMember("test1");
 array5.AddMember("test1");

 arrays.push_back(array1);
 arrays.push_back(array2);
 arrays.push_back(array3);
 arrays.push_back(array4);
 arrays.push_back(array5);

 std::string str = arrays[0].ToString();
```

Error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x026574BD in Message.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation reading location 0x00000000.

DebugInfo:
Already on the first push_back the members of the first entry are corrupt.
Before I implemented the Copy-Constructor the program crashed already on the second or third pushback, I guess because the vectore had to realocate his entries and could not find them? As I sad, first time I had to deal with this problem.

So my question is: did I do the copy-constructor wrong? or am I totally on the wrong way and it has nothing to do with it?

I looked at many other Stackoverflow questions dealing with similar problems and tried to follow the advises there, but I guess I did something wrong along the way.

Please let me know if I need to provide additional information.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Probably: Rule of three (5) - missing assignment operator

Comment: wow, thank you for the fast answer! I will look into it. In the meantime, could you tell me if I did the implementationof the clone() function in cjsonvalue.cpp right? I was very unsure with just returning a NULL there.

Comment: You know that `Clone` is *not* virtual, right?

Comment: I added an assignment operator (I hope I did it right) but the problem is still there. I edited the code in the OP to reflect my changes.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what purpose is `CJsonValueNumber(const CJsonValueNumber * value);` supposed to be serving? It certainly isn't invoked by `return new CJsonValueNumber(*this);` And your `JsonArray` will invoke undefined behavior on that assignment operator you added unless the rvalue *exactly* matches the size of `this->members`. Since you've gone to this much trouble, why not just finish this off and post a *real* [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so as to spend less time wondering what *isn't* shown, and more time on what *is* ?

Comment: @WhozCraig 6 the complete jsonplus library can be looked at [here](https://code.google.com/p/jsonplus/source/browse/branches/jsonplus-0.2.0/?r=19#jsonplus-0.2.0%2Fsrc). All my changes are listed in my op above. I'm unsure what purpose 'CJsonValueNumber(const CJsonValueNumber * value)' serves. How would I change my assignment operator to prevent the undefined behaviour? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

`CJsonValue::Clone()` method needs to be virtual. If a `CJsonArray` object stores a collection of `CJsonValue` objects (as opposed to `CJsonValueNumber` or otherwise) then the compiler can't know that `CJsonValueNumber` wants to override the `Clone()` method if it isn't virtual.

This would lead to `CJsonValue::Clone()` is always being called instead of `CJsonValueNumber::Clone()`. At that point you have NULL references in your array, which would likely lead to your access violation at `0x00000000` (`NULL` is defined as `0`, or `0x00000000`).

Since `CJsonValue` is an abstract class anyway (`CJsonValue::ToString()` method is virtual void), I would make `CJsonValue::Clone()` virtual void as well. This would guarantee the Clone method has to be implemented by inheriting classes.

To summarize, change your declaration of `CJsonValue::Clone()` to:

```
LIB_PRE virtual CJsonValue * Clone() = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed it and I am sure this would have been a problem as well, but I still get the same error executing the main-function